# How to add own eventfilter to QDeclarativeView

Tags: qt, qml, qwidget

for a project, i wrote my own `QWidget`.
This widget includes a `QDeclarativeView` that represent a ListView of QML.
For my widget, i've implemented a eventfilter. The problem is, that this is not triggerd in the `QDeclarativeView`.
I've installed the filter with `installEventFilter` to the view. But it will not trigger.

What's wrong with it?

Greetings

Comment: Show a minimal case that reproduces the problem. Please keep it in one file (`main.cpp`), simply put `#include "main.moc"` at the end of the file. Remember to re-run qmake once you add the first `Q_OBJECT` line.